# unfollow user not woking: acts as follower gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-follower

I am attempting to allow a user to follow or unfollow a user via the acts as follower gem. This is my show view:

```
     <tbody>
                      <% @runs.each do |run| %>
                          <td><%= run.user.try(:username) %><p> 
                            <% if current_user.following?(@user) %> 
                            <%= link_to "Unfollow", unfollow_user_path(@user.username), method: :delete %></p>
                            <% else %>  
                            <%= link_to "Follow", follow_user_path(@user.username), method: :post %> </td> 
                            <% end %>
                          <td><%= run.Run_Type %></td>
                          <td><%= run.Location %></td>
                          <td><%= run.Start_Time %></td>
                          <td><%= run.Pace %></td>
                          <td><%= run.Miles %></td>
                          <td><%= run.Run_Date %></td>
                          <td><%= link_to 'Show', run %></td>
                          <% if run.user == current_user %>
                          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_run_path(run) %></td> 
                          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', run, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
                           <% end %>
                        </tr>
                      <% end %>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
```

and my routes:

```
  resources :users, only: :show, param: :username do
member do
  post 'follow', to: 'follows#create'
  delete 'unfollow', to: 'follows#destroy'
end
```

end

and my controller:

```
   class FollowsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
    Follow.create(followable: user, follower: current_user)
    redirect_to user_path(user.username), notice: "Successfully followed user"
  end

  def destroy
    user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
    Follow.find_by(followable: user, follower: current_user).destroy
    redirect_to user_path(user.username), notice: "Successfully unfollowed user"
  end
end
```

finally my model:

```
   class Follow < ApplicationRecord

  extend ActsAsFollower::FollowerLib
  extend ActsAsFollower::FollowScopes

  # NOTE: Follows belong to the "followable" and "follower" interface
  belongs_to :followable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :follower,   :polymorphic => true

  def block!
    self.update_attribute(:blocked, true)
  end

end
```

When "Follow user" is clicked, the user gets the notification "successfully follow user" but the expected action should be that that link then would say "unfollow user" however, this does not happen.

[image]

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnirg.png]

Comment: What happens when you refresh the page? Does it change to "unfollow user"?

Comment: it does not, the link still says "follow user"....However, the notification / notice / alert does say "successfully followed user"

Comment: Can you add a snippet of the follow POST request in your server log? I don't think you can make a POST with a `link_to` unless you are doing some sort of javascript with it.

Comment: I am learning rails and therefore do not how to view my server log..... apologies I am a newbie

Comment: No problem. How do you start your rails server? Do you use the terminal? Is there a window showing a bunch of text flying by?

Comment: yes! I didn't realize that this is what it was called, I pasted a screen snip

Comment: Ok great. Clear that screen (<kbd>Cmnd</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, then click on the button to follow one person, then go and copy and paste the request log in your post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188503/discussion-between-westman2222-and-rudyonrails).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The acts_as_follower rubygems version 0.2.1 is outdated, from 2013. You need to change your gemfile line from:

```
gem 'acts_as_follower'
```

to

```
gem 'acts_as_follower', github: 'tcocca/acts_as_follower', branch: 'master'
```

Or you can just accept my PR here: https://github.com/westche/sample_app/pull/1